# HTML tags from Database not interpreted as HTML in browser

Tags: php, html

So I have a record in the database from a field named `comments`.

```
Comment from <a href='www.google.com'># 12345</a><b>Hello</b>
```

but upon displaying in the browser, it's not being interpreted as HTML but as a plain text and displaying as is.

I'm expecting:

Comment from [# 12345](http://www.google.com)**Hello**

Code so far:

```
$comment = $adb->query_result($result,$i,'comments');
$comment = wordwrap($comment, 150, " ", true);
$comment = htmlentities($comment, ENT_QUOTES);
```

I've tried to comment out `htmlentities` line but still displaying the same. Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Was your comment encoded before going into the database?

Comment: can you show the view?

Comment: I'm not using MVC and well Cully, the one that I've posted is what in the database. The one with HTML tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

`$comment = html_entity_decode($comment);`

You can also try using [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

`$comment = htmlspecialchars_decode($comment);`

Comment: Which one did you go for?